Are all alignments of A, P, Sa and Sp attested?
I put together this graphic to visualize what I think are all possible alignments of A, P, Sa and Sp:

(Sorry the text is so small; I had to downsize the image so the height wouldn't take up the full screen, the full-size image can be found here)
S has to be split into Sa and Sp to account for active-stative, at minimum.
I have labeled as many as I recognize have names, but that's only 7/15 of them.
Do the other 8/15 have names? Do they all exist?... do any of them exist?
(One thing I notice about all these weird 8/15 is they all split Sa =/= Sp, that might have something to do with it)

tbh, it's the diagonal groupings that seem especially odd to me. It really wouldn't surprise me if some of these are unattested and, due to this, haven't been given names before

so I'd be extremely surprised in 4, 9, & 10 existed. The others seem to imply a rather odd saliency hierarchy in terms of which distinctions they make, but are all partitioning the thematic space in ways that are somewhat plausible

if I had to name these systems, I'd probably systematise the entire system more, by naming after the (typical cases of) uniquely identified themes. So 5, 6, 7, & 8 would be ergative, accusative, nominative, and absolutive alignments respectively. (note that the first two are already common abbreviations). 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, & 14 would then be ergative-absolutive, nominative-accusative, absolutive-accusative, nominative-absolutive, ergative-accusative, & ergative-nominative respectively (although note that 9 & 10 would now conflict with the previous names of 5 & 6). 4 could then be cross

(this is just how I'd do it, not any suggestion as to how these are actually called, hence it not being an answer)

Is there any particular reason 15 introduces four entirely new colours instead of reusing the three used in 1–14?

15 can evolve by sound change into any of 9–14, no matter how unnatural and unstable those systems are. Gong deep enough into dialectology may reveal real life examples of all of them.

@SirCornflakes is 15 actually attested though? Even tripartite is quite rare, and adding an active-stative split to the intransitive clause seems like it would be extremely rare. Certainly not implausible though

Found this paper (in French)  on academia.edu: https://www.academia.edu/2590675/Un_alignement_quadripartite_en_b%C3%A9s%C9%A8ro_Quatre_arguments_nucl%C3%A9aires_dans_la_langue_des_Chiquitanos_de_Bolivie about quadripatite alignment in a language of Bolivia.

Another caandidate for quadripartite alignment are the Dingir languages of Australia, but it is only from a reddit comment that hints that, needs further checking.

@SirCornflakes The 'Dingir languages of Australia'?? I'm pretty sure there are no such languages in Australia; the only mention of 'Dingir' I can find on Reddit is a conlang.

@GastonÜmlaut Ah, thanks for the clarification! I was just quickly searching.

@GastonÜmlaut I'm pretty sure that's my conlang you're talking about :) I don't know how it got confused for being Australian but I know there are some Australian languages that have tripartite at least
